# sql - Using aggregate functions (min/max) as part of select statement

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to return the minimum and maximum prices for a villa booking system. I have a look up table that stores the price for each week for each villa.

I am using the min and max functions to do this within the select but I'm having lots of problems. Can anyone explain where i'm going wrong? Heres the sp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spVillaGet 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@accomodationTypeFK int = null,
@regionFK int = null,
@arrivalDate datetime = null,
@numberOfNights int = null,
@sleeps int = null,
@priceFloor money = null,
@priceCeil money = null
```

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT tblVillas.name, 
       tblVillas.introduction,
       tblVillas.italian_introduction,
       tblVillas.uk_content,
       tblVillas.italian_content,
       tblVillas.sleeps,
       tblVillas.postcode,
       tblLkUpRegions.regionName,
       tblLkUpAccomodationTypes.accomodationType,
       MIN(price) As MinPrice,
       MAX(price) As MaxPrice

FROM tblVillas

LEFT JOIN tblLkUpRegions on tblVillas.regionFK = tblLkUpRegions.regionID
LEFT JOIN tblLkUpAccomodationTypes on tblVillas.accomodationTypeFK = tblLkUpAccomodationTypes.accomodationId    
LEFT JOIN tblWeeklyPrices on tblWeeklyPrices.villaFK = tblVillas.villaId

WHERE

    ((@accomodationTypeFK is null OR accomodationTypeFK = @accomodationTypeFK)
     AND (@regionFK is null OR regionFK = @regionFK)
     AND (@sleeps is null OR sleeps = @sleeps) 
     AND tblVillas.deleted = 0)

GROUP BY tblVillas.name
```

Comment: Need more detail on what error you're getting

Comment: What are the problems, errors you are facing ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't elaborate on *what* problems you are getting, but this is probably one: you need to specify **all** the non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause i.e.:

```
GROUP BY tblVillas.name, 
       tblVillas.introduction,
       tblVillas.italian_introduction,
       tblVillas.uk_content,
       tblVillas.italian_content,
       tblVillas.sleeps,
       tblVillas.postcode,
       tblLkUpRegions.regionName,
       tblLkUpAccomodationTypes.accomodationType
```

From your follow-up comment is appears that some of your columns are of a data type that can't be used in a GROUP BY clause.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT tblVillas.name, 
           tblVillas.introduction,
           tblVillas.italian_introduction,
           tblVillas.uk_content,
           tblVillas.italian_content,
           tblVillas.sleeps,
           tblVillas.postcode,
           tblLkUpRegions.regionName,
           tblLkUpAccomodationTypes.accomodationType,
           (SELECT MIN(price) FROM tblWeeklyPrices where tblWeeklyPrices.villaFK = tblVillas.villaId) As MinPrice,
           (SELECT MAX(price) FROM tblWeeklyPrices where tblWeeklyPrices.villaFK = tblVillas.villaId) As MaxPrice
FROM tblVillas
LEFT JOIN tblLkUpRegions on tblVillas.regionFK = tblLkUpRegions.regionID
LEFT JOIN tblLkUpAccomodationTypes on tblVillas.accomodationTypeFK = tblLkUpAccomodationTypes.accomodationId    
WHERE
        ((@accomodationTypeFK is null OR accomodationTypeFK = @accomodationTypeFK)
         AND (@regionFK is null OR regionFK = @regionFK)
         AND (@sleeps is null OR sleeps = @sleeps) 
         AND tblVillas.deleted = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help

When I Group By and include all the columns from the select except the two functions I get the following error

```
Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spVillaGet, Line 22
```

The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spVillaGet, Line 22
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: I have updated my answer about this.  NB you shouldn't really submit an "answer" to clarify your question - you should update the question and/or comment on my answer.

Comment: He doesn't have the rep to post comments yet, but you're right that changing his question would have been better.